# Why is the directory index tree deleted?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

Today i wrote a script that iterates over a folder with 2.5m files.
the first problem was, that iteration took very long, because the directory index needs to build up first. after the inital build up it should be stored next to the folder, so further iterations should be faster.

this behaviour could be seen as the following:

- while the build up was in progress, the script just hung.
- if you stopped the script and restarted it, the memory size was immediatly set to the value of the previous run (so if you had 400MB indexes, you will start from there and not from 0)
- after the whole index was build up, even after a restart the directory could be iterated in seconds, rather than in hours.

More information about the Directory Index Tree can be found here: http://wiki.sleuthkit.org/index.php?title=NTFS

But there is now one problem: After i deleted several files, the indexing starts again. So somehow the index tree is not reorganised, but deleted and new build up.
Is there any time limit after the Tree is invalidated or is it just the size of the tree?

is there any way to speed up access to large folder structures by forcing to keep the tree always on the filesystem?